# I'm having a hard time returning a variable in django views.

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am having a hard time getting access to the rawCorpus variable that I return in my views.  When ever I test it with an alert: alert({{ rawCorpus }}) it pops up with undefined as the message. I really need a way to test things as I go along in views. IE: a print method for my individual variables that doesn't have to go through the return process.

```
views.py

def homesite(request):
rawCorpus = ""
corpusitems = CorpusItem.objects.order_by('name')
if (request.method == 'POST') and "namefortextinput" in request.POST:
    f = CorpusItemForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        new_corpusitem = f.save()       

elif (request.method == 'POST') and 'selectedCorpusChoiceTokenizeWords' in request.POST:
    g = CorpusChoiceForm(request.POST)
    if g.is_valid():
        new_corpuschoice = g.save()
        rawCorpus = g.__getitem__(name)


Models.py

class CorpusItem(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.CharField(max_length=9000)


   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

class CorpusItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CorpusItem

   def __str__():
    return name 
    from django import forms

class CorpusChoice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CorpusChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CorpusChoice
```

Comment: I think you should use `alert('{{ rawCorpus }}')` (with quotes). You can also look into your sourcecode to see what is really in the output.

Comment: Did you include all of your code?  Not seeing any place where you're actually passing rawCorpus to your view

Comment: There's no good reason to call `__getitem__` directly. Use `g['name']`.

Comment: As @rednaw said, use quotes around your variable (so it gives `alert()` a string instead). As for debugging, it is a good thing to print them with the Django [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/), even though I personally use standard `print`s.